# Overflow:hidden moves div inside

Tags: html, overflow, hidden, move

I encountered a thing I could not explain, neither did I find some answers here or with Google.

I have the following code:
(head and other structures are kind of truncated here...)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="ajaxdiv">
        <div id="page0">
            <p>000000000 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
#container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ajaxdiv {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
```

the problem is now, that by having the line 'overflow: hidden;' in my wrapper the div inside, namely the ajaxdiv is displaced. its moving down around 10-20px and I don't know why this is happening.

Do anyone have an explanation?

Comment: You have a 100% better chance of an answer if you setup a http://jsfiddle.net example